# Only hear noise of audio out of DAC

Tags: audio, dma, adc, stm32cubeide, dac

I have been trying to hear the real time audio I get from the **ADC** into the **DAC** and listen to it through the headphones I connected. I am using a **STM32G01CE-EV** board, but when I try to listen to the data I give through the **DAC** I only hear noise. I have tried to change the frequency in order to adjust it more to my microphone, **44Khz**, but I still get only noise on my headphones.

I am using **ADC** and **DAC** with **DMA** circular buffer mode, everytime a Timer event occurs it holds the data for the buffer and then send it half buffer completed to the **DAC**.

Any idea why I only hear noise?

Comment: better question for the sibling forum  https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved, as soon as I managed what I was introducing in the DAC and sampling it with another timer at 22Khz, in order to comply with Nyquist Shannon.

If anyone finds this problem, just check what type of data are you entering, in case your dac is configured as your adc, just check the same type of data is getting in the input and through the output.